# Speed different on aligned-size array and non-aligned-size array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-alignment

I try to operate on aligned-size array and non-aligned-size array, but the result is a puzzle me, the non-aligned-size array is faster than aligned-size array, This is my code:

```
TimeMeter timeMeter;

const int N = 100000;

_Tp A[64];
_Tp B[65];

int szA = sizeof(A);
int szB = sizeof(B);

//  Method 1
timeMeter.start();
for ( int n = 0; n < N; n++ )
{
    memset(A, 0, szA);
}
timeMeter.stop();
printf("Method 1 Time usage = %f ms\n", timeMeter.span());

//  Method 2
timeMeter.start();
for ( int n = 0; n < N; n++ )
{
    memset(B, 0, szB);
}
timeMeter.stop();
printf("Method 2 Time usage = %f ms\n", timeMeter.span());
```

- When `_Tp` is `char` (8): Method 1 cost 2.195ms and Method 2 cost 2.175ms
- When `_Tp` is `int` (32): Method 1 cost 13.313ms and Method 2 cost 5.987ms
- When `_Tp` is `double` (64): Method 1 cost 14.266ms and Method 2 cost 11.304ms

Comment: Do you need to reset TimeMeter after each measurement??

Comment: @MitchWheat `stop` and a subsequent `start` probably resets it

Comment: @Seth: that's what a sane API would do.

Comment: Can you give us more information? What machine is this? Is this x86/x64? What compiler? So far, I'm not able to reproduce your relative performance results.

Comment: If you swap the order of your methods and run "method 2" first, does "method 1" run faster?

Comment: Benchmarking a simple `memset` over less than 1MB of memory is a silly benchmark.

Comment: The dataset fits entirely into 1-4 cache lines, which kind of makes the whole thing a bit futile. With only one concurrent thread, is in principle even possible that these 1-4 cache lines are not even written out more often than once at the end. Also I'd be interested what kind of timer that is. If that's a naive implementation on top of a system timer on _the most common OS on the planet_, for example, then the measurement cannot capture invervals as small as you posted them reliably at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your benchmark is invalid for several reasons:

1. Nothing here appears to check alignment at all. You simply have two different sizes of arrays. Plus memset also won't care much about alignment since it works at the byte level.
2. As ildjarn pointed out, memset on such a small amount of memory is not very good. It is simply too fast, but that in itself is not a huge problem...
3. ...you aren't using any of the memory that your are setting. An optimizer could validly eliminate all but one call to your memset.
4. As you don't use any of the memory the CPU may actually be doing a lot of reordering/caching, in particular between the loops.
5. Your benchmarks have a running time near the timeslice size on many OS's (you don't say which one, so I'll guess 1ms timeslice like on many Linuxes). That means OS switching overhead could be greatly altering the results of your test.
6. Your arrays are allocated one after another. CPUs tend to predict ordering, thus this could actually affect the results.  Try switching the orders of your loops and see if it makes a difference.
7. You don't indicate what timing you are using. Many timers simply don't have the resolution needed for ms accuracy tests, so you could be getting a bias in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Types only have to be aligned within themselves, i.e. `char` must be aligned on a 1-byte boundary, `int` must be aligned on a 4-byte boundary, and `double` must be aligned on an 8-byte boundary.

To really test unaligned accesses, try doing

```
_Tp* A = (_Tp*)((char*)(new char[num * sizeof(_Tp)]) + 1);

...

delete[] (_Tp*)((char*)A - 1);
```

Furthermore, `memset` treats everything like a pointer to a series of `char`s, which are never unaligned, so no matter what you do with the array you can't get `memset` to do an unaligned write.